# How to get "paymentToken" value using Reg Exp Extractor in Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

**My Response Code Looks like: -**

{
  "data": {
    "transactionId": "04dxf19-xx-42e3-a4f7-75xxa012x4a",
    "paymentUrl": "https://wpp-test.wirecard.com/?wPaymentToken=t45QiNvkZX5fYxxxxEEpFz8mcK2ZirBhVMrvuo"
  },
  "message": "Success.",
  "code": "OK",
  "appVersion": "2.0.0.47",
  "machine": "CHPV345678"
}

**and from the above code, I want to extract the value inside = wPaymentToken** ( i.e t45QiNvkZX5fYxxxxEEpFz8mcK2ZirBhVMrvuo)

I tried the following options without success -

1)  "paymentUrl":
    "https://wpp-test.wirecard.com/?wPaymentToken=(.+?)" 
 2)
    wPaymentToken=(.+?)"

Can you please help me , as while checking the value in Debug Sampler it always remains enmpty

Here Is my Test Plan : It contains two REGEX in 1 thread

[image]

Here is the reson , why I only want paymentToken because Final URL is not same as the URL that we extracted using JSON

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Second option should work fine:

[image]

Wouldn't be easier to extract the whole `paymentUrl` attribute value? It can be done using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) with a simple [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression of `$.data.paymentUrl`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dimitri for looking into it, But the second option does not work for me.. Here I would like to mention that - My thread contains almost 21 requests and this is the second time I am using REGEX inside my threadgrouop.

Comment: Show your test plan

Comment: @Dimitri - If I go with JSON Extractor , I am able to extract the complete URL - Can you let me know how to use this extracted URL in HTTp request or if not possible Can you show me how to extract only paymentToken using JSOn Extractor?

Comment: Just put this complete URL at the "Path" field of the HTTP Request sampler and you should be good to go

Comment: Hi Dimitri , I had added one more screen shot - Depicting the last problem - If I use URL in path field of HTTP Request - ( both URL's are not same)